# Unexpected AST node : query using find_in_set()

Tags: java, mysql, hql

I was trying to write a query using find_in_set() function and write the code as below:

```
@Repository
public interface AbcDAO extends JpaRepository<AbcEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<AbcEntity> {

    @Query("SELECT mb FROM AbcEntity mb where if(mb.assignto_user is NOT NULL , find_in_set(:user , mb.assignto_user) , mb.assignto_user IS NULL ) "
            + "and  find_in_set(:role , mb.assigned_to) group by mb.id order by mb.id DESC")
    public List<AbcEntity> abcInboxList(@Param("user") Integer user, @Param("role") Integer role);
   
}
```

And the dao method is called as below:

```
List<AbcEntity> abcList = abcDAO.abcInboxList(abcDTO.getUser_id(), abcDTO.getRole_id());
```

Whenever i tried to run the code, getting an error as unexpected AST node

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.xxx.dao.AbcDAO.abcInboxList(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:51) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 84 [SELECT mb FROM com.xxx.model.AbcEntity mb where if(mb.assignto_user is NOT NULL , find_in_set(:user , mb.assignto_user) , mb.assignto_user IS NULL ) and  find_in_set(:role , mb.assigned_to) group by mb.id order by mb.id DESC]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 84 [SELECT mb FROM com.xxx.model.AbcEntity mb where if(mb.assignto_user is NOT NULL , find_in_set(:user , mb.assignto_user) , mb.assignto_user IS NULL ) and  find_in_set(:role , mb.assigned_to) group by mb.id order by mb.id DESC]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

**Note: ** The query is running with proper result in MySql workbench.

Any help is going to be appreciated. :) Thanks in advance